# Splitting up a phone number in php

Tags: php, css

Ok so i have a variable $phone which contains the string (407)888-9999 and I have this code

```
 if($phone != ''){ $phone = "<span id='telephone'>{$phone}</span>";}
return $phone;
```

This works fine but now the client wants to have a some padding in between the area code and the next three numbers. So i need the code to be like this

```
<span id='telephone'><span class='spacer'>(407)</span>888-9999</span>";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given no one else mentioned this, I would strip out all non-numeric characters from the number. Once done you can use a regex to easily get the numbers, this way any format is valid and pretty much no matter what the user enters you can format it how you want it:

```
$phone = preg_replace("~[^0-9]~", "", $phone);
preg_match('~([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})~', $phone, $matches);

if (!empty($matches)) {
    $display = "<span id='telephone'><span class='spacer'>(" . 
                $matches[1] . ")</span>" . $matches[2] . "-" . $matches[3] . "</span>";
}else {
    $display = "An invalid phone number was entered.";
}
```

Should do it not matter how the phone number is entered as long as there are 10 digits.

**UPDATE**

You could also use the `preg_replace` technique with `substr` and forego the need for `preg_match`. This would actually be my preferred solution.

```
$phone = preg_replace("~[^0-9]~", "", $phone);

if (strlen($phone) == 10) {
    $display = "<span id='telephone'><span class='spacer'>(" . 
                substr($phone,0,3) . ")</span>" . substr($phone,2,3) . "-" . substr($phone,5,4) . "</span>";
}else {
    $display = "An invalid phone number was entered.";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you know for sure that the string is properly formatted?  If so, you can break it up into substrings:

```
 $phone = "<span id='telephone'><span class='spacer'>{substr($phone, 0, 5)}</span>{substr($phone, 5, 8)}";
```

Comment: On the other hand: if you don't know if the string is properly formatted this will fail with a poof of errors :) In wich case you need a lot of additional logic to find out the proper-formatted-ness of a string. In which case a regular expression might proof a much simpler solution.

Comment: If the data is being retrieved from the user, I would agree.  However, in that case there's more sanitizing that should be done (beyond the scope of this question).  If the data is being retrieved from the database, you may be able to assume it was sanitized during input, and save yourself some unrequired overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$input = "(407)888-9999";
$area_code = ''; 
$ph_num = $input;
if(strpos($input,')') !== false) { // if area-code is present.
        list($area_code,$ph_num) = explode(')',$input); 
        $area_code .= ')';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iff the phone number is always in the same format, you can split it with:

```
list($area,$phone1,$phone2) = sscanf($phone,'(%d)%d-%d');
```

or

```
sscanf($phone,'(%d)%d-%d',$area,$phone1,$phone2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [regular expressions](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
<?php 
  preg_match("/(\([^\)*]\))(.*)/", $phone, &$matches);
  var_dump($matches);
  print "<span id='telephone'><span class='spacer'>({$matches[1]})</span>$matches[2]</span>";
?>
```

Comment: If the string is already known to be properly formatted (by any previous verification), regular expressions are overkill - overly complex and overly processor-hungry.

Comment: To quote the often-quoted Jamie Zawinski: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.'  Now they have two problems."

Comment: @James Burgress, though funny, and probably sometimes even trough, there /are/ lots of valid and good places where to use regexes. Parsing phone-numbers is one of such areas.

Comment: Of course, but for simply inserting a space (which is all the OP requested, we presume he's validated the number format already), a regular expression is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a simple str_replace like this, as long as you're sure the phone numbers have brackets around the area code ...

```
$phone = "(902)555-1234";

if($phone != ''){
    $phone = str_replace(")", ") ",$phone);
    $phone = "<span id='telephone'>{$phone}</span>";
}
return $phone;
```